# Vue.js roadmap and backward compatibility

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We are working in an environment where the overall web application is maintained by a core team, but developers internal and external use the frameworks and tool to develop on the application.
If the frameworks used are not backward compatible, overtime it will be impossible to upgrade the systems as other developers used frameworks to develop (old versions for example).

We would like to choose a modern JS framework, thinking a bit more serious about Vue.js.
Can anyone share thoughts about Vue.js roadmap and upgradability of the framework as it goes to V3, V4, etc?

Is the core team's mission to keep it the new versions backward compatible? not to break any APIs offered in the previous versions, etc?

Comment: I would limit this question to Vue, as it will be easier to get a specific answer.

Comment: Done, I am more interested in VueJs because of its component capability.

Comment: I don't mean to be picky, but I still see the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I and my team have been using `Vue.js` for quite some time for almost 2 years. Before that, we used Angular for 4 years.

I can surely say that future Vue.js will not be **fully** backward compatible with past Vue. This was true when v2 was released. In fact, this applies to any major JS framework out there. Most of them will not be backward compatible. Look at `Angular`, `Hapi`, `Koa`, `Rx.js`, etc.

There is a good reason for that. JS is evolving in ways you or me as a single person cannot comprehend in one go. Not all browsers support all features. Web components are coming since 2015 and still a way for them to reach a general consensus. For example, in case of Vue 3.0, the idea is to use ES proxies that will probably be **backward incompatible**. As web components get adopted by browsers, the idea of Vue.js component will change and it will again be backward incompatible.

Having said this, `Vue.js` is unlike any other framework out there. The core team is trying its best to preserve core framework compatibility. What happened with Angular 1 -> 2 or Vue 1 -> 2, there is a least likely chance of that happening

As long as you are using `Vue` public API, you should be good. The transition if any will definitely be smooth, less head-spinning and you will have a clear upgrade (read as - temporarily compatible) path.

Graceful evolution is one of the reasons why we are using `Vue` as our large-scale application framework.